# Does it make a difference if I close the database connection after try/catch rather than in finally

Tags: java

In following two examples, I am 1) closing the database in the `finally` block and 2) closing it after the `try` ... `catch`. Does it make a difference which approach is used?  If no, what is the point of `finally`, as we can release resources without using it?

```
try{
    // initialise a database connection
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally{
    db.close
}
```

Second

```
try{
    // initialise a database connection
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
db.close
```

Comment: In the version without `finally`, if a throwable is thrown that is not caught (or if your code returns) `db.close` will not be reached

Comment: no throws is here then no use case right ?

Comment: Java [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html): _"The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs. But finally is useful for more than just exception handling — it allows the programmer to **avoid having cleanup code accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break.** Putting cleanup code in a finally block is always a good practice, even when no exceptions are anticipated."_

Comment: Consider using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) too if the thing you need to close implements AutoCloseable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to explain why `finally` is better / necessary is to point out the flaws in this version of the code:

```
try {
    // initialise a database
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
db.close();
```

The first problem is that if some exception that is a subtype of `Error` is thrown, then the `try ... catch` won't catch it.  `Error` is a subtype of `Throwable` but not of `Exception`.

<sup>You might counter that one should not attempt to recover from an `Error` exception.  That is true in many contexts, but not in others.  For example, if this code was executed in a worker thread, a lot of frameworks will try to create a new thread to replace the one that died.  That would result in the database handle leaking.</sup>

The second problem is that you are catching and squashing exceptions.  Indeed, for the code as you have written it, you *have to* do this for the `db.close()` at the end to be executed.  This might work in your example, but it won't work in general.  For instance, what if you need to return something from this code ... or allow the exception to propagate for the caller to deal with.

The third problem is that you are catching `Exception` so that you can close `db.close()` in all cases.  However, by doing this, you are most likely catching exceptions that should not be caught at this level.  For example, if something withing the try block throws an NPE, you should not "squash and recover".  Instead, you should allow the exception to propagate.

Note that using `finally` means that you don't have to worry about leakage in the case of `Error`s, recovering when you don't want to, or catching more exceptions than you mean to.

Now you can attempt to work around the three problems above without using `finally`, but it introduces other problems.  (For example you could catch and then rethrow `Exception` with a `db.close()` in the handler, but then you would typically need to declare the enclosing method as `throws Exception`!)

---

Note that calling `printStackTrace()` like that is not advisable.  A better approach is to use a logging framework ... so that the error reporting can be managed via a configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

`Finally`, the block is a `safe point` to close the resource as `finally block` will execute in `every situation` until the `System#exit` called. It may happen that catch is also `thrown an exception`, in that case, your resource will not close if you put outside after catch block.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the question is what is the difference between closing the database connection in the finally block versus after the finally block.

I will assume that the database was opened INSIDE the try block. If the code inside the try block threw an exception and your closed the database only after the finally block, you won't close the database when the exception is handled.

The correct way to do this is to close the database in the finally block.  The finally block will run unconditionally, whether an exception was thrown or not.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a little more specific example:

```
try{
    // initialise a database
} catch (SocketException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally{
    db.close
}
```

This will cleanup even if the exception was *not* a SocketException.

```
try{
    // initialise a database
} catch (SocketException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
db.close
```

This won't. It will just bubble up the exception.

(I chose SocketException randomly. This of course goes as well for other Exceptions, Throwables etc)

Baseline: Using the finally block to perform clean-up fortifies your code against *unexpected* exceptions and exceptions thrown in your catch-blocks.